# codeigniter 4 datetime helper vs php date formatter?

Tags: php, datetime, codeigniter-4

I've just watched a tutorial video on YouTube that uses CodeIgniter4's `datetime helper` to get the current datetime, but isn't that also achievable using the regular PHP date formatter `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`? is there any advantage on using the datetime helper? afaik, php 7 already supports `Locale` and timezone, right? the video was posted on Jul 14, 2020.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. If that has any advantage depends on the rest of that code

Comment: yt = YouTube, ci = CodeIgniter, 4 = for, afaik = As far as I know.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware is that a suggestion to edit the words in the question? or did someone ask for clarification on the abbreviations I used?

Comment: It is, what I had to work out, to understand your question. Do with it what you want. If you want your question to reach as many people as possible, I would suggest to not use unnecessary abbreviations. The same is true when you write code: Do not abbreviate unnecessarily. I (rightly?) assume you do the same there.

Answer (score 2):

##### PART 1:

> I've just watched a tutorial video on YouTube that uses CodeIgniter4's
> `datetime` *helper* to get the current datetime...

**Answer:** CodeIgniter 4 has **no** built-in `datetime()` helper. It's most likely that the tutorial author defined a custom "*date_helper*" function under `system/Helpers/date_helper.php`.

[Date Helper Available Functions](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html#available-functions)

- `now(...)`
- `timezone_select(...)`

##### PART 2:

> ...isn't that also achievable using the regular PHP date formatter
> `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`?

**Answer:** If you're referring to [retrieving a UNIX timestamp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) that defaults to the current local time if the second `timestamp` parameter is omitted or null, then YES.

##### PART 3:

> is there any advantage to using the `datetime` helper?

**Answer:** Refer to *PART 1:*

The closest I could find relating to "*datetime*", was the [BaseModel's "date-time casting" process](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/7107e782f86b3394c22cf980c85bc385b42b9207/system/BaseModel.php#L1212):

```php
    // ...

    protected function timeToDate(Time $value)
    {
        switch ($this->dateFormat) {
            case 'datetime':
                return $value->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            //...
    }
```

##### PART 4:

> afaik, php 7 already supports `Locale` and timezone, right?

**Answer:** Correct.

[The Locale class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php)

[The DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

##### Extra Notes (Creating a date-time object based on a particular timezone):

###### Native Style:

```php
$datetime = new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
print $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');
```

###### CodeIgniter 4 Style:

```php
$datetime = (new \CodeIgniter\I18n\Time("now", "Europe/Berlin", "de_DE"));
print $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');
```

The advantage of using [CodeIgniter 4's `system/I18n/Time.php` class](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/system/I18n/Time.php), is that you would now have access to many rich helper functions that allow you to easily manipulate and retrieve relevant date-time information. I.e: `today() | yesterday() | tomorrow() | getDay() | getMinute() | getWeekOfYear() | getAge() |  getQuarter() | getTimezoneName() | setTimezone() | addDays() | addMonths() | humanize() | sameAs() | subMonths() | etc...`.

The second advantage with CodeIgniter 4's `Time` class is that it [extends](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.extends) the native `DateTime` class. Meaning that you implicitly also have access to all the capabilities of the native `DateTime` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
use CodeIgniter\I18n\Time as DateTime;
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the how is important, but much of the site's quality level comes from people going out of their way to explain why. While a correct code-only answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques/148274#148274)